# remove duplicates from a group of arrays

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following group of arrays in one array, where the content of them is a group of posts :

```
array:5 [▼
  "in" => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#371 ▼
      +"id": 61
      +"created_at": "2019-11-29 08:12:11"
      +"updated_at": "2019-11-29 08:12:11"
      +"title": "Sports test "
      +"body": "Test answer"
      +"ttype": 0
      +"cat": 0
      +"a_id": 61
      +"tag": ""
    }
    1 => {#372 ▶}
  ]
  "out" => []
  "other" => []
  "fol" => array:17 [▶]
  "tag" => []
]
```

The arrays :

```
    $Final_updts['in'] = $all_update_in;
     $Final_updts['out'] = $all_update_out;
     $Final_updts['other'] = $all_update_oth;
     $Final_updts['fol'] = $follow_psts;
     $Final_updts['tag'] = $post_tags;
```

There might be some posts repeated in more than one array. I tried to use `array_unique($Final_updts);`, but received `Error exception: Array to string conversion`

Is there any easy way to do this, or I have to modify the 5 queries to prevent any duplicate results ?

Comment: You need to show us your attempt, some proper example data with duplicates and the expected result from that, including what you're currently getting. Where are you getting the data from to begin with? Please edit the question to include all needed info.

Comment: You may use laravel's own collection library to handle this problem. Check this page: https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-unique

Comment: Imho getting clean data in the first place is always better than getting "dirty" data and cleaning up afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to get unique items by id. Lets use [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) to solve this problem.

```
$results = collect($array)->collapse()->unique('id');
```

Pls let me know if I got it right.